# How can i use a text file to create a figure in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have row data in a text file that looks like this:

```
2.40 2.22 5.48 -5.93 -3.67 5.84 0.70 1.44 3.26 -12.27 -5.65 0.81 -1.17 5.83 5.50 -1.67 7.10 -7.14 1.25
1.47 15.78 -10.79 0.70 -1.58 3.77 4.67 3.62 -2.19 3.43 2.82 -0.52 -1.61 6.30 3.57 6.06 8.07 2.03 2.95
2.64 -3.78 -12.95 2.73 -2.18 -1.16 0.35 6.90 5.57 -1.64 1.45 8.78 2.27 -1.03 0.91 0.64 0.02 1.93 2.14
6.19 1.87 12.23 -7.71 14.92 1.30 -1.04 0.93 6.75 4.91 21.72 4.22 4.02 -0.16 2.06 1.89 0.23 0.91 4.36
-0.03 -2.78 0.79 -5.98 -0.18 -1.19 5.57 -7.95 1.95 2.86 2.85 -6.89 -0.53 -6.59 2.14 3.75 1.22 2.49 1.72
5.52 -4.71 -5.38 -7.50 4.21 3.38 4.14 0.92 -2.23 -13.98 0.98 1.45 -3.50 3.04 -5.04 -1.35 -6.37 -3.57 -1.96
-0.62 0.86 -1.99 -10.95 7.00 -1.85 5.00 -1.33 -1.50 -0.69 10.36 4.60 -4.69 4.19 7.17 -0.74 5.00 5.53 -3.02
1.91 1.85 -7.72 -2.67 3.62 -0.52 -1.13 4.40 -2.64 1.26 3.40 -3.17 -10.48 -2.22 -1.04 0.64 -5.93 2.47 -0.86
-0.12 -8.24 -11.59 -15.03 -3.21 3.27 5.67 5.21 -0.40 -12.33 0.62 8.42 -5.89 3.03 4.07 -0.16 -4.43 1.78 2.12
8.09 -3.20 6.90 12.89 8.92 -0.01 -1.97 4.53 -1.92 -17.77 4.76 0.04 8.83 -1.41 1.73 1.55 6.93 -0.95 0
11.80 -6.92 11.79 12.82 0.42 5.93 4.01 -0.94 -6.49 -2.12 -0.01 1.43 -1.41 3.09 2.27 3.36 3.63 1.44 0
16.23 -2.27 1.66 -12.50 3.10 0.66 5.93 8.31 -2.00 3.69 1.91 5.86 1.11 2.05 2.09 1.06 -4.03 2.92 0
```

Each column represents a year from 1999 to 2017 in order (going from left to right) and each row represents a month from Jan to December in order (going top to bottom).

I have to write a code that transforms this data to a figure. The code needs to be as general as possible so that any other data can be added and still run the code. The biggest problem I'm having is how I have to assign the columns to years and the rows to months. 
The following is a link to a pdf file containing the figure and the data file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgzg6lbpr3t0ib9/Inl%C3%A4mningsuppgift2_HT17%20%281%29.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I'm seeing "I need to create a really generic figure of some sort". Okay, now as a specific question so that we can help. What should this figure look like? What have *you* already tried? Also please format your data so it actually looks like it's in columns, this will help readability.

Comment: I added 2 links that shows how the figure should look like. I didn't try anything yet i don't know how to begin.

Comment: I added a pdf file containing the figure and the data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to import the data in a general way would be to use the graphical Matlab import tool

```
uiimport
```

select output type as "Numeric Matrix"

then you have your data in this example as 12x19 double

rehape the array to a vector can be done in this case just by data(:)

```
figure;plot(data(:))
```